# Invoking lambda many times in parallel seems to execute in concurrent batches of 50, not with the higher specified reserved concurrency

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**TL;DR For a batch of 500 lambdas executed in parallel, I'm observing them being executed in concurrent batches of 50, despite specified reserved concurrency of 500.  Why is that?**

Hi,

I'm new to AWS lambda and having trouble understanding the concurrency behaviour I'm seeing.

I am invoking a lambda function "calc-group" [from the AWS web interface or CLI], which invokes another lambda function "calc-number" 500 times in parallel, where the latter has specified reserved concurrency of 500.  [The lambdas all run and the calculation results are all fine].

"calc-number" takes about 1s to execute, but "calc-group" takes 10s to execute.  The [Concurrent executions chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGt9Q.png) suggests I'm getting a concurrency of only 50, consistent with 10x timing I'm seeing.  *[Note: a more detailed implementation of "calc-number", not shown here, also gave evidence that only 50 lambda execution contexts start with each handling 10 requests sequentially].*

I'm using `Promise.all` on promises for synchronous `lambda.invoke` calls.

I have read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html but don't understand what is happening.

Below is a much stripped down example isolating the behaviour.  *[Note: I know the memory here is much higher than needed, but it makes the timing more stable and the original code is CPU bound benefiting from this setting].*

I would much appreciate any suggestions for how I could get all 500 executing in parallel...

Many thanks!

*EDIT: simplified the code having read more on error handling in async node.js handlers + minor tidy-up*

*EDIT: FYI, if I call calc-group repeatedly in parallel, the concurrent executions of calc-number increase proportionately.  e.g. if I call calc-group 5 times in parallel (I tested from CLI), I then see 250 concurrent executions of calc-number, although 2500 requests are made and executed.  (Beyond 10 parallel requests of calc-group, requests start getting rejected).  **So it seems there is some other cap/constraint of 50, perhaps related to where the lambda calls originate from?  Is there any documentation on that or way to increase that?***

---

**Lambda #1, calc-group**

- Runtime: Node.js 12.x
- Memory(MB): 2048
- Timeout: 0 min 15 sec
- *Role that allows calling calc-number*

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const n = 500;

    const promises = [];
    for (let x = 1; x <= n; ++x) {
        promises.push(
            lambda.invoke({
                FunctionName: "calc-number",
                Payload: JSON.stringify({x})
            }).promise()
        );
    }

    const data = await Promise.all(promises);

    const results = data.map(d => {
        const payload = JSON.parse(d["Payload"]);
        return payload["result"]
    });

    const sum = results.reduce((a, x) => a + x, 0);

    return { sum };
};
```

---

**Lambda #2, calc-number**

- Runtime: Node.js 12.x
- Memory(MB): 2048
- Timeout: 0 min 3 sec
- Reserve concurrency: 500

```js
const util = require('util');
const sleep = util.promisify(setTimeout);

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const x = event["x"] || 0;

    const result = x * x;

    await sleep(1000);
    
    return { result };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calling code is limited to 50 SDK requests in parallel because you don't appear to have changed it from the default.

> When using the default of `https`, the SDK takes the `maxSockets` value from the `globalAgent`. If the `maxSockets` value is not defined or is `Infinity`, the SDK assumes a `maxSockets` value of 50.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-maxsockets.html

Building and signing each API request takes CPU time so fixing this might not take you as far as you would like in a single Node process, but it will remove the barrier at 50.

Comment: Fantastic, that is super helpful.  

I just tried passing an https.Agent with maxSockets: 500 into constructor of AWS.Lambda, and now have 500 concurrent calls to calc-number.   

I will read that whole developer guide....

Comment: I'm not sure best way to link so you get credit, but I think your answer may be relevant to this question too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557089/why-only-50-instances-working-on-aws-lambda  (I don't have the reputation to comment on that question with a link to your answer).

Comment: Oh, and now I find someone asked basically the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629780/how-can-the-aws-lambda-concurrent-execution-limit-be-reached, which you answered then too.   Somehow didn't find that when searching before asking!  Thanks again.